# Magento2 Custom Order Number Sequence

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

I am trying to replace default order/invoice number sequence in magento2. I have completed successfully by using following code.

**di.xml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"
>
    <type name='Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Manager'>
        <plugin name='Test\SalesSequence\Plugin\Model\Manager' type='Test\SalesSequence\Plugin\Model\Manager'/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Manager.php file**

```
<?php
namespace Test\SalesSequence\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Manager as Sb;
use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence as Sequence;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection as AppResource;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Sequence\SequenceFactory as SequenceFactory;
use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\ResourceModel\Meta as ResourceSequenceMeta;

class Manager extends Sb {

    protected $checkoutSession;

    private $storeId;

    private $type;

    protected $sequenceFactory;

    protected $resourceSequenceMeta;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        SequenceFactory $sequenceFactory,
        ResourceSequenceMeta $resourceSequenceMeta
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->sequenceFactory = $sequenceFactory;
        $this->resourceSequenceMeta = $resourceSequenceMeta;
    }

    public function aroundGetSequence(Sb $sb, \Closure $f, $entityType, $storeId) 
    {
        return $this->saleSeq(Sequence::class, [
            'meta' => $this->saleSeqMeta($entityType, $storeId), 'pattern' => $this->pattern()
        ]);
    }

    private function pattern() 
    {
        //last order id.
        $lastCreatedOrderNumber  = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();

        //last order created day
        $orderCreatedAt = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getCreatedAt();

    }
}
```

I don't want to use `$this->checkoutSession` to get last order id from the database.

I want to get the last order id placed in the store.

Is there anyway, I can get last order id here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection` instead of `CheckoutSession` to get last order for a specific store.

This collection is basically being used to populate order data in sales order grid in Admin Panel and we can filter this collection by `created_at` field to get the last placed order as below.

```
class LastOrder
{
    protected $orderGridCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection $collection
    ) {
        $this->orderGridCollection = $collection;
    }

    public function getLastOrder($storeId)
    {
        $lastOrderData = $this->orderGridCollection
            ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('eq' => $storeId))
            ->setOrder('created_at','DESC')
            ->getFirstItem()
            ->getData();

        var_dump($lastOrderData);
    }
}
```